# Visual Studio Code clean terminal

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am programming in C in VSCode and I am trying to clean my terminal from other things like `PS` or `cd` and some other text. I tried a lot of things how to make my terminal clean but it only works for Python or Java but not for C because my `launch.json` is different.And do you know how to get rid of the free space from first picture it only happens when i run my code more times.

[image]

And this is how my `launch.json` looks like if it helps.
Thanks for any help.

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "C/C++ Runner: Debug Session",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "c:/Users/miroh/OneDrive/Počítač/programko vsc/build/Debug/outDebug",
      "args": [""],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "",
      "environment": [],
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "D:/MinGW/bin/gdb.exe",
      "externalConsole": false,
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "clean"? Do you want to remove the build-command that is usually shown in the terminal? Why? If there's errors it's sometimes very good to see the commands. Or the actual errors themselves without processing.

Comment: So this is how it should look like ? Bcs i saw some videos when they have only output there nothing else only clean output thats what i mean and idk why is there free space with no text.

Comment: Well it shouldn't be all that empty space between the prompt and the command. That's a problem. What those "videos" Are doing I don't know, you have to ask the authors.

Comment: They are modifying launch.json but it doesnt work for my and they are using other language too btw original video is here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NSZqn1VrzVc&t=229s